Ubuntu only bootable when Kodachi USB plugged in
Ok this is a weird one. I have Ubuntu installed as one of the OS's on my computer. I decided, as a giggle, to install Kodachi onto a USB stick. This is how my boot menu looks (apologies for the poor lighting):

As you can see there is an ubuntu option. However, booting into it brings you to the GRUB prompt:

(I'm not sure what information to include here as I'm unfamiliar with this prompt)
However, if you boot into "ubuntu" with the Kodachi USB stick plugged into the computer, you're brought to the expected GRUB menu:

And then I can boot into Ubuntu and run everything as normal, including if I unplug the USB stick.
How do I bring my Ubuntu out of this USB stick GRUB menu and back into my regular boot menu?

When you installed, did you create ESP on external drive & install boot loader/grub to external drive? Then UEFI would boot external by default, but when not found boot internal. It sounds like your install to external overwrote install to internal drive in internal drive's UEFI & ESP settings. You should be able to boot to internal drive and reinstall grub. sudo grub-install If only booting from this system, then you  can boot from internal drive's grub after sudo update-grub to find other system. But if you want to use with other systems, it must have its own ESP & grub.

@oldfred sudo grub-install followed by sudo update-grub fixed it! thanks!

If kernel gets updated on external drive, you have to re-run the update on internal drive to have latest kernel. You can create boot stanza that boots a link Ubuntu provides to latest kernel in 40_custom, so you do not have to update.  Best to have ESP on external drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi & https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

If installing to any second or external drive with any newer system that is UEFI, you need to partition in advance with gpt partitioning and have ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) as first partition. Not all installers let you choose where to install boot loader/ESP, many now do & will create only create gpt if drive was gpt originally.
If only planning to use with one system, you can have UEFI boot from an existing ESP on internal drive. But if removable drive, you would need it always connected as UEFI would make that default. You then can boot to internal drive and reinstall grub to make it first in boot order. Assumes many defaults for UEFI grub install. Must be from previously UEFI bootable install with correct mount of ESP.
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub

The update of grub should add external drive to internal drive's grub menu. you can add your own boot stanza to 40_custom. If you do not add your own entry using the links that get updated with every new kernel, you have to run the update-grub with every external drive update. Not sure if other distributions provide a link to newest kernel in boot like Ubuntu & flavors.
Direct UEFI boot of an external drive may break if installed like an internal drive. Or an "ubuntu", if Ubuntu or flavor,  entry will stop working when drive disconnected. But grub now installs /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, so external drives can boot from UEFI entry for external drive by name/label, just like booting live installer.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive
